# Is chemAxon check of validity of a smiles the same as RDKit check?

Tags: cheminformatics

I am working on an AI-based drug design application, I want to verify the validity of the produced molecules (which are in smiles representation). I found a solution to this using the RDKit library the following way:

```python
from rdkit import Chem


def check_validity(smi):
    m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi, sanitize=False)
    if m is None:
        print('invalid smiles')
    else:
        print("valid smiles")
        try:
            Chem.SanitizeMol(m)
        except:
            print('invalid chemistry')
    return v
```

However, most similar work in the literature use the ChemAxon-checker software (which I think is a closed-source software):
https://docs.chemaxon.com/display/docs/structure-checker-getting-started.md.
This might make the comparison of performances unreliable.

So my question is: Is the ChemAxon-check of validity of smiles the same as my RDKit checker function?

Note: I am not a chemist, I come from a computer science background

Comment: Not a proper answer, but you might be interested in this : https://depth-first.com/articles/2021/09/22/beyond-smiles/ Richard Apodaca is trying to better 'formalise' SMILEs here

Comment: One *potential* pitfall working with SMILES is that there are multiple dialects of SMILES. Not obvious for small molecules like benzene, pyridine, etc.; however with growing complexity of molecular structures, it is better a) to stick with one form, or b) to convert all into one form, and then sanitize them. E.g., [OpenBabel](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/SMILES_format.html#smiles-format) lets you choose canonical, universal, or inchified; [PubChemPy](https://pubchempy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/properties.html#identifiers) isomeric ones. And Marvin/ChemAxon?

Comment: Maybe «reliable» doesn't fit what you intend to express for a meta analysis how well (e.g., in terms of describing a structure without ambiguity [bijective relation between structure and reduced representation/SMILES] and chemical reason [e.g., charges, valences, tautomerism]; rate of processing, ease of scaling) ChemAxon vs. RDKit performs. The [discussion board](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/discussions) or [issue tracker](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/issues) might be resonate earlier (by RDKit's developers/user community) to this interesting question.